# submit php form with different input type using javascript/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have to submit a `form` with some fields, `like multiple checkboxes selection` and some `hidden input fields` via ajax and replace html content with response. finally i go with javascript/ajax...but where i was wrong?

```
 <?php include( 'session.php');
 $userid=$_SESSION[ 'Userid'];
 include( 'connection.php');
 ?>

    <head>
     <script>
 function myFunction() {
var soi = document.getElementById("sweaterownerid").value;
var osp = document.getElementById("osweaterpic").value;
var osi = document.getElementById("osweaterid").value;
var value = [];
        $("input[name*='" + sweater+ "']").each(function () {
       // Get all checked checboxes in an array
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
         value.push($(this).val());
            }
        });


var dataString = 'soi1=' + soi + '&osp1=' + osp  + '&osi1=' + osi + '&value1=' + value;
if (soi1 == '' || osp1 == '' || osi1 == '' || value1 == '') {
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
} else {
// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Usercloset1.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(response) {
$('#mydiv').replaceWith(response);
}
});
}
return false;
}
</script>
    </head>
   <div id="mydiv">
    <div class="padding-top">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="shop_item" style="width:100%;">


                <form id="myForm">
                    <?php
                    $sweaterid=$_GET['d'];
                    $sownerid=$_GET['e'];
                    $opic=$_GET['f'];             

                    $query1="select * from `usersweater` where `Sweaterid`='$sweaterid'";
                    $result1=mysql_query($query1);
                    $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
                    $sweaternikname=$row1['SNickname'];

                    ?>

                    <div>
                        <ul class="sweaters">
                            <li> <h4><?php echo $sweaternikname; ?></h4> <img src="upload/<?php echo $opic; ?>"> </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="sweater1">

                            <?php
        $query="select * from `usersweater` where `Userid`='$userid' && `Swap`='0' ";
                   $result = mysql_query($query);


            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                                $sid = $line[Sweaterid];
                                $img = $line[Sweaterpic];
                                $nikname = $line[SNickname];
                                $size = $line[Size];
                            ?>

<li> <h4><?php echo $nikname; ?><input type="checkbox" name="sweater[]" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>" /></h4> <img src="upload/<?php echo $img; ?>"> </li>

<?php  } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                    <input type="hidden" name="sweaterownerid" value="<?php echo $sownerid; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="osweaterpic" value="<?php echo $opic; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="osweaterid" value="<?php echo $sweaterid; ?>">

                    <input type="submit" name="next" onclick="myFunction()" value="NEXT" class="btn woo_btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 30px;">
                    <input type="button" name="cancel" value="CANCEL" class="btn woo_btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
    </div>
```

I want to pass the selected option to another page, which I do now using form action. But I want it dynamically without reloading page. I am new to ajax/javascript.

Second thing is, how can I handle the response, where submitting this form I want to replace first page content with the reponse that we get using ajax. This means replace all html content with other page's html content. I atteched the file which I want in response after submit.

```html
<div class="padding-top">
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="shop_item" style="width:100%;">

    <div style="text-align:center;">
     <h4>Are you sure you want to swap?</h4>
    </div>

   <form action="Usercloset2.php" method="post">
    <?php
    include('session.php');
    include('connection.php');
    
    
    
    foreach ($_POST['value1'] as $sid){
   $query1="select * from `usersweater` where `Sweaterid`='$sid'";
    $result1=mysql_query($query1);
    $row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $sweaternikname=$row1['SNickname'];
    $sweaterpic=$row1['Sweaterpic'];
    ?>

    <div style=" ">
     <ul class="sweaters">
      <li> <h4><?php echo $sweaternikname; ?></h4> <img src="upload/<?php echo $sweaterpic; ?>"> </li>
     </ul>
    </div>


    <!-------requester's own sweater details--------------->
    <input type="hidden" name="sid[]" value="<?php echo $sid;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="snikname[]" value="<?php echo $sweaternikname;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="spic[]" value="<?php echo $sweaterpic;?>">
    
    <?php } ?>

    <!-------requester's show intrest that sweater details--------------->
    <?php
    $sownerid=$_POST['soi1'];
    $opic=$_POST['osp1'];
    $sweaterid=$_POST['osi1'];
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="sweaterownerid" value="<?php echo  $sownerid;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="osweaterpic" value="<?php echo  $opic;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="osweaterid" value="<?php echo  $sweaterid;?>">
    
    <div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">
     <input type="submit" name="next" value="NEXT" class="btn woo_btn btn-primary">
     <input type="button" name="cancel" value="CANCEL" class="btn woo_btn btn-primary">
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <hr>
 </div>
```

Comment: `<script>????</script>` Why don't you give it a try first? There are plenty of info on SO and Google on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it though this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $("#your_button_id").on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#your_form_id") .submit();
     })
})
```

**Ajax**

```
$("#your_form_id").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('URL_HERE', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  });
});
```

Comment: `without reloading the page`, this will definitly reload the page

Comment: then you should use ajax, $("#your_form_id").on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post('URL_HERE', $(this).serialize(),function(response){
                console.log(response)
            });
        });